# Fingir que aparelho não tem GPS

Tags: android, gps

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de "enganar" o dispositivo durante o debug falando que o mesmo não tem GPS. Não quero apenas desabilitar, se não durante o desenvolvimento o GPS irá ser encontrado.

Tenho a finalidade de verificar se o dispositivo tem o GPS presente ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que pelo depurador não exista nenhuma função pré definida pra tal coisa, mas você pode criar uma `if` e força-la a ser `false`, por exemplo o seu código deve ser algo como:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    //Código com GPS
} else {
    //Código sem GPS
}
```

Se quiser fingir que o GPS não está ativo faça algo como (aplique o `false`):

```
if (false && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    //Código com GPS
} else {
    //Código sem GPS
}
```

Ou pode simplesmente comentar está linha no manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

E deixe assim:

```
<!-- uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" / -->
```

Comment: Obrigado, acabei esquecendo que poderia negar a existência do GPS no dispositivo, valeu.